# Cauchy-Schwarz problem (Maybe)

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I believe that this may require Cauchy-Schwarz

$$|\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}|\leq |\vec{u}|\cdot|\vec{v}|$$

to solve.

Let $y_1,y_2,\ldots ,y_p$ be $p$ positive numbers and let $i$ be a positive integer. Let $Z_i$ be the number defined by the formula

$$Z_i:=\left(\frac{y_1^i+{\cdots}+y_p^i}{p}\right)^{\frac{1}{i}}.$$

Show that if $y_1,y_2,\ldots ,y_p$ are not all equal, then $Z_i$ is strictly less than $Z_{2i}$.

**Edit**

$$\left(\frac{y_1^i+{\cdots}+y_p^i}{p}\right)^2<\frac{y_1^{2i}+{\cdots}+y_p^{2i}}{p}$$
(raise each side to the $2i$ power.)

Setting $u_k=v_k=y_k$ results in the following statement:

$$\left(y_1^2+{\cdots}+y_p^2\right)^2\leq{}\left(y_1^2+{\cdots}+y_p^2\right)\cdot{}\left(y_1^2+{\cdots}+y_p^2\right)$$

Comment: Should the $x$s in the large parens be $y$s?

Comment: @John Yes, thank you.

Comment: Also: have you written out the inequality $Z_i < Z_{2i}$ and done some algebra to find other statements equivalent to it that might be easier to prove?

Comment: @John Yes, I have tried for many hours.

Comment: I've fixed the $x$ vs $y$ problem now.

Comment: Great. Show us something to which this inequality is equivalent, and maybe we can help.

Comment: @John I simplified it

Comment: You might want to justify that simplification (hint: things are positive!). You could also square both sides to get an equivalent statement (again, needs justification). What happens if you set $u_k = v_k = y_k$ and apply C-S? It doesn't quite work out, but could you modify it a little to make it do so? Maybe multiply or divide by some constant?

Comment: @John But how is this related to the other inequality?

Comment: If you expand out the right hand side, you get all the terms you want...and a bunch more. Of course, you need some "p"s in there as well, hence my hint about constants. Since robjohn has now provided a complete proof, I'm going to bow out.

Comment: @John My math professor the key to this problem is to find what vectors to use. What vectors do I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\vec{u}=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\frac{x_1^p}{n}\\
\vdots\\
\frac{x_1^p}{n}
\end{array}
\right),
\vec{v}=\left(\begin{array}{c}
1_1\\
\vdots\\
1_n
\end{array}
\right)
$$
\begin{align*}
\Vert\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}\Vert &\leq\Vert\vec{u}\Vert\cdot\Vert\vec{v}\Vert\\
\frac{x_1^p}{n}+{\cdots}+\frac{x_n^p}{n} &\leq\sqrt{\frac{x_1^{2p}}{n^2}+{\cdots}+\frac{x_n^{2p}}{n^2}}\cdot\sqrt{n}\\
\frac{x_1^p+{\cdots}+x_n^p}{n} &\leq\sqrt{\frac{x_1^{2p}+{\cdots}+x_n^{2p}}{n}}\\
\left(\frac{x_1^p+{\cdots}+x_n^p}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} &\leq\left(\frac{x_1^{2p}+{\cdots}+x_n^{2p}}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{2p}}
\end{align*}

Comment: Didn't you want to show strict inequality when the items were not all identical?

Comment: @robjohn I agree that it should be explicit, but this is exactly the condition for equality in Cauchy-Schwarz; $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ must be linearly dependent, i.e. all the $x_i$ are equal.

Comment: @you-sir-33433: I understand that, but since Dia McThree was answering their own question, I thought they might want to make that distinction.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a standard proof of Cauchy-Schwarz that shows why equality only holds when all the terms are the same.

---

Let $x_k=y_k^i$ and define
$$
\bar x=\frac1p\sum_{k=1}^px_k\tag{1}
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1p\sum_{k=1}^p(x_k-\bar x)^2
&=\frac1p\sum_{k=1}^px_k^2-\frac2p\sum_{k=1}^px_k\bar x+\frac1pp{\bar x}^2\\
&=\frac1p\sum_{k=1}^px_k^2-2\bar x\bar x+{\bar x}^2\\
&=\frac1p\sum_{k=1}^px_k^2-{\bar x}^2\\
&=\frac1p\sum_{k=1}^px_k^2-\left(\frac1p\sum_{k=1}^px_k\right)^2\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Note that the left side of $(2)$ is positive, giving strict inequality, unless $x_k=\bar x$ for all $k$.

Comment: I don't get it :(

Comment: @DiaMcThrees: Now it should make more sense :-)

Comment: How can I apply this to my problem?

Comment: If you let $x_k=y_k^i$ as suggested above, then this should translate directly to your problem.

Comment: @DiaMcThrees: does it still not make sense? I notice that you've unaccepted this, but have not accepted another answer. You are free to do this, but I was wondering if it was because you were still not convinced by this proof. I have added a bit more, in case you were still not convinced.

Comment: @DiaMcThrees: I see from a comment elsewhere that you liked that another answer didn't answer the whole question. However, I had stopped at $(2)$ and only added $(3)-(5)$ when you seemed confused about how to apply $(2)$ to your problem. I will remove $(3)-(5)$ since I also thought they were a bit too much.

Answer (score 0):

Further hints:

(1) Can you find a proof for $i = 1$ and $p = 2$, i.e., can you show that 
$$
\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^2 < \frac{x^2 + y^2}{2},
$$
provided that $x \ne y$, and both $x$ and $y$ are positive? How does $x \ne y$ figure in your proof?

(2) In the restated goal, you have a bunch of numbers raised to the $i$th power, and the $2i$th power. How about letting $x_j = (y_j)^i$, so that $x_j^2 = (y_j)^{2i}$. Does that help simplify things a bit?

To respond to the comment ("I can't figure out #1"), I'm going to write this one out. Of course, if you can't write this one out, there's no hope of doing the more general proof; it's one of the reasons I often try to prove an easy case of a theorem before moving on to the general case. Here goes:
We want to show that if $x$ and $y$ differ, then 
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^2 &< \frac{x^2 + y^2}{2},
\end{align}
I'll do so by sequentially altering the inequality to equivalent inequalities:
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^2 &< \frac{x^2 + y^2}{2}\\
\frac{x^2+2xy+y^2}{4} &< \frac{x^2 + y^2}{2} & \text{by algebra}\\
x^2+2xy+y^2 &< 2x^2 + 2y^2 & \text{multiply through by 4}\\
2xy&< x^2 + y^2 & \text{subtract $x^2 + y^2$ from both sides}\\
0&< x^2 -2xy + y^2 & \text{subtract $2xy$ from both sides}\\
0&< (x-y)^2& \text{factor right hand side}\\
\end{align}
Now observe that since $x \ne y$, the right hand side is nonzero.

If you read @robjohn's answer, you'll see that it's just those steps, written out in reverse order and generalized to a sum of $p$ items, I believe.

Comment: I can't figure out #1. Thank you so much or your help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I didn't think of using standard algebra, since I am taking linear algebra. I haven't had much experience with this level of math.

Comment: Can I accept two answers? Your answer helped me solve this, without giving the answer directly.

Comment: Dunno. I expect not. On the other hand, I wasn't doing it for the credit. :)

Comment: @DiaMcThrees: Ah, this is why you unaccepted my answer; I was wondering about that. If this answer was more helpful to you, please go ahead and accept it :-).